# Twitter Rest Api "Could not authenticate you"

Tags: android, rest, twitter, httprequest, scribe

I am using scribe to make a GET request for a user's timeline, however upon doing this I receive instead the error code 32, and "Could not authenticate you".

Here is the Signature Base string (Percent Encoded): GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fuser_timeline.json&include_entities%3Dtrue%26oauth_consumer_key%3DzQpuKd5h8n6mqiumNM6u7d2uj%26oauth_nonce%3DtPPVcV5YnPAKXsNdNzGLhuCwnoJdkrCW%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1426942034%26oauth_token%3D2889494926-MZqy7vBnhQDzJrnhEIR3cQQrl7xNLVw59ph9OLR%26oauth_version%3D1.0

Here is the Authorization Header: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="zQpuKd5h8n6mqiumNM6u7d2uj,oauth_signature="0wg95cu9WsA0ooldwb8yWAsW5qw%3D"",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1426942034",oauth_token="2889494926-MZqy7vBnhQDzJrnhEIR3cQQrl7xNLVw59ph9OLR",oauth_nonce="tPPVcV5YnPAKXsNdNzGLhuCwnoJdkrCW",oauth_version="1.0"

I am not sure why I am getting this error message - Even when I use the signature generator - https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/tools/signature-generator/7765982?nid=731 - I still get this error. Any ideas?